# Angular Js ng-click not firing?`

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-events, angularjs-ng-click

I'm having the weirdest issue getting ng-click to fire in my angular app.

Here's what I'm dealing with:

```
<div class="popup" id="perks-popup" ng-if="perksPopup === true">

    <div class="popup-bkg" ng-click="perksPopup = false;"></div>

    <div class="popup-content">
        <div class="popup-close" ng-click="perksPopup = false;">

            <img class="scalableImg" src="img/icons/close-blue.png" alt="">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and here is the base controller:

```
(function(){

    "use strict";

    Caribou2015.controller('BaseController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'Dates', function($rootScope, $scope, Dates){
        console.log('base controller init');

        //overlay and popup states
        $rootScope.welcomePopup = false;
        $rootScope.perksPopup = true;
        $rootScope.calPopup = false;
      

    }]);
})();
```

with this setup what I expect to happen is that the perks popup div will show up and when I click its background or the popup-close div, it gets removed by ngIf. Well it shows up just fine but clicking the close or the background does nothing. I even added a `$rootScope.$watch` on the variable to see if it changes and I get nothing. It seems like the ng click event isn't firing at all. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't pollute `$rootScope` its bad pattern, do use `service/factory`
>   while you wanted to share data between various component.

`ng-if` does create a prototypically inherited child scope on that element valued data type will not get there value populated in that `div`, you need to add `$parent.` to access scope variable, before an As you are using scope variable `ng-if` that is causing an issue you need to follow the dot rule while declaring model, suppose that would be `$scope.model={}` in scope then assign all the properties and use it on html.

**Markup**

```
<div class="popup" id="perks-popup" ng-if="model.perksPopup === true">

    <div class="popup-bkg" ng-click="model.perksPopup = false;"></div>

    <div class="popup-content">
        <div class="popup-close" ng-click="model.perksPopup = false;">

            <img class="scalableImg" src="img/icons/close-blue.png" alt="">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.perksPopup = true;
```

Comment: Awesome. I hate $rootScope in there because i wasn't sure if it was any kind of weird scope issue. Thanks for the reminder though to remove that. Also thanks for the tip with ngIf